# Joomla website migration from IIS7/PHP5.3 to Apache 2.4/PHP5.6.13: The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available

Tags: apache-2.4, joomla, mysql5.1

it's been 2 days I can't figure out why I can't connect to MySQL from my Apache Website.
I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server that hosts the company website on IIS7, with Joomla 1.5.3 and PHP 5.3 (installed in c:\program files (x86)\php\v5.3).

It's (still) running smoothly and with no issues.

We need to migrate it to Apache 2.4 (x64, installed on c:\Apache24), obvoiusly keeeping Joomla where it is :-)

Installed PHP5.6.13 x64 (in c:\PHP_5.6.13)

I managed to bring up & running both Apache and PHP, but now when I try to connect to the Apache site (localhost:8081/site) I get the following error

Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available.

I'm stuck on it.
I've enabled both mysql and msqli extensions in php.ini
I've set the mysql default host in php.ini
Changing the $dbtype in Joomla configuration to 'mysql' or 'mysqli' has only the effect to change the name of the adapter that is not found in the error message :-)

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: running phpinfo() showed me that they are expecting php.ini in c:\windows. Since I don't want to move that file, I created the PHPRC environment variable pointing to c:\PHP5.6.13, but I read that is needed to restart the server in order to achieve changes.
Since this is a production server, I will restart this evening :-)
I'll post the results....

EDIT (AND CONCLUSION): The problem was, apart of copying php.ini in c:\windows (the environment variable didn't do the trick), that I set the wrong path for php Extensions and Apache was searching for c:\Apache24\ext instead of c:\PHP5.6.13\ext... it was so clearly reported in Event Viewer....
Just for the sake of completness, in the end I abandoned (for now) the migration because I found [this](http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/) connector from IIS to Tomcat that let me set up the redirection in 5 minutes. (with Apache I had issues with something that was messing up with paths, so one virtual site was referenced as server root and the other one did not respond)... I was thinking about something misconfigured in joomla but have no time to serach and fix it)

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MySQL server using workbench?

Comment: The same MySQL database is used by the "other" site, the one that is run on IIS and that I need to migrate... so I assume it's working...